# Horizontal bar graph in collapsible table style in iOS

Tags: ios, core-plot, expandable

I have requirement to develop Horizontal Bar graph in collapsible table style. I am using core plot framework currently. Does it support such animation? Do I need to use some other API.
I need the graph to be exactly like Collapsible/Expandable table view.

I believe we can do it using graph view embedded in a custom cell, has anyone tried yet?

Please help.
Thanks

Something like below image.
[image]

Comment: Yes, you can achieve this by making Custom Cell which can contain a GraphView. You are on right track.

Comment: Have you tried?. If yes, please provide me the code snippet.